# SEARCHING with some condition in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, search

i have a web project using codeigniter.
i have a problem with searching in my project. i have to show the multiple result from searching page with some keyword. 
here is my **Model**

```
function find_user($like){
    $this->db->from('user');
    $this->db->like('name', $like,'after');
    $result =$this->db->get();
    return $result->result_array();
}
```

and in my user table, include

```
id | name | place_code
```

in the user table , column `place_code` is use to show the place from the user

here is my **Controller**

```
    function search(){

    $query       = $this->input->post('query_cari');

    $find = $this->m_user->find_user($query);
    foreach ($find as $key) {
        $code = $key['place_code'];
        if ($code == '1') {
        $place = 'Secretray';
        }elseif($code == '2'){
        $place = 'OB';
        }elseif($code == '3'){
        $place ='Manager';
        }
    }

    $data['result'] = $find;
    $data['place']  = $place;
    $this->load->view('home/search',$data);
}
```

that's my code for controller, include a `logic` for get the position from user in office. but the problem is, when i get a result just `1` result, the `place` is right. but if i get more than 1 result, `place` is going wrong and just show the `place` for all result is the `place` from the last result in searching.
what i want is, all result just shown their own `place`.

here my **VIEW**

```
 <?php foreach ($find as $key: ?>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Place</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $key['id'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $key['name'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $place ?></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Don't know if this fixes the problem but looks like you've got a typo: $this->db->like('name', $liek,'after');

Comment: Where is your `cari_keluarga()` function??

Comment: sorry is my fault, i was update my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal that you always get the last place because your logic is not correct. First, you have an error in your model. Secondly, you can improve your model code:

```
function find_user($like)
{
   $this->db->like('name', $like, 'after');

   return $this->db->get('user')->result();
}
```

Now, in your controller you want to change the variable `place` according to the value of `place_code`. You are allowed to add a new key (or change an existing one) in real time to the `stdClass()` as follows:

```
foreach($find as $i => $result)
{
   // By default, we assume the 'place_code' is equal to '1'
   $find[$i]->place = 'Secretray';

   if($result->place_code == '2')
       $find[$i]->place = 'OB';
   else
       $find[$i]->place = 'Manager';
}

$data['find'] = $find;
$this->load->view('home/search', $data);
```

Finally, in your view:

```
 <?php foreach ($find as $result){ ?>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Place</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $result->id; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $result->name; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $result->place; ?></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: haha owh god, i forget about `result` in codeigniter, so thanks, my problem solved